# Why does backref refer to wrong page?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I use `biber` with `backref`, but `backref` points to a wrong page. Option `backref` always gets it one page wrong.

Why does it so and how can I solve the problem?

Here's what might be related to the problem:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref,style=authoryear,isbn=false,dashed=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage[%
  colorlinks,urlcolor = black,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,
  bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,
  plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black
]{hyperref}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%start counting afresh after toc
\setcounter{page}{2}
```

Comment: Please give a complete MWE. Your code works for me. So, there must be something else in your document.

Comment: Instead of resetting the page counter: What do you think about using `\pagenumbering{roman}` (or `Roman` or `alph` or `Alph`) for the frontmatter and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after the `\clearpage` for the mainmatter, using the `hyperref` package with option `plainpages=false`, and in Adobe Reader `Edit > Preferences > Page Display > Page Content and Information > Use logical page numbers` (or the equivalent in your preferred PDF viewer)?

Comment: @Stephen: That sounds like a good option! I would totally consider choosing it as the best answer, if only it was one...

Comment: OK, posted as answer. Glad if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer *why* `backref` refers to the wrong page, but it could be a solution to your problem nevertheless.

Do not reset the page counter manually but use different page numberings:

- `\pagenumbering{roman}` (or `Roman` or `alph` or `Alph`) for the frontmatter, possibly with a pagestyle not printing the page number at all if you do not like it. (You already use `\thispagestyle{empty}`, `\pagestyle{empty}` could be used.)
- `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after the `\clearpage` (for two-sided documents: `cleardoublepage`) for the mainmatter

Give the option `plainpages=false` to the `hyperref` package, so that `hyperref` treats for example page `ii` and `2` as different pages. (You already did this in your example, I just wanted to explicitly mention it for possible other users faced with a similar problem.)

When you use in Adobe Reader `Edit > Preferences > Page Display > Page Content and Information > Use logical page numbers` (or the equivalent in your preferred PDF viewer), it will show the page "name" and the number of the page. For example with 10 pages with names i to x in the frontmatter, page "5" is the 15th page and the reader shows "5 (15 of ...)", where "..." is the total number of pages. This also has the advantage that entering "5" there indeed takes you to the page named "5" and not to the fifth page (named "v").

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: hyperref option `hypertexnames` must be set to `true` (the default value).

When you see the following error message...

> (pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
>   (`name{page.1}`) has been already used, duplicate ignored ).

...you surely use `\pagestyle{empty}` without changing the numbering. Fix: Use a page numbering you don't use at other places in the document. Here, I used `\pagenumbering{Alph}` right after `\begin{document}`.

(Answer based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58962/9075)