# Wrong pages in biblatex backref link with hyperref

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, back-referencing

I've encountered the same problem as described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93889/why-does-backref-refer-to-wrong-page) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150476/biblatex-backref-links-to-wrong-page-using-hyperref) post:
I'm using `hyperref` with biblatex option `backref` and the created backref links lead to wrong pages. The answers above didn't help. Any help  is appreciated.
Here is my MWE, which reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[hyperref=auto, backref=true, style=chem-angew, backend=biber, sortcites=true, chaptertitle=true, doi]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\cite}{\supercite}

\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true, hypertexnames=false, breaklinks=true, linkbordercolor={0 0 1}, pdfpagelabels, plainpages=false, pdfencoding=auto, psdextra, pdfborder={0 0 .5}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@article{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{title}
We are citing \cite{A01,C03} and \cite{B02}.
\null
\chapter{title}
\null
Now we cite \cite{C03}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

edit: now `plainpages = false` (was `plainpages = true`) in the code `hypperref` option, as suggested in first link -did't work, either.

edit2: I've tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58941/hyperref-pagebackref-page-number-and-link-in-references-wrong?rq=1) answer, which suggested to turn `hypertexnames = true` and it seems to work, but i'm not sure, if this has unpredictable consequences to my PhD thesis which i'm unable to see right now.

Comment: You might want to refer to this question [What does the `hyperref` option `hypertexnames` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188/35864). If you do not reset any counters or re-use them you *should* be fine. Of course if it is your PhD thesis you're dealing with you want to be very sure nothing is messed up, so I recommend to apply some extra scrutiny to those links in your document.

Comment: The reason for why this works - I think - is that with `hypertexnames` enabled `hyperref` creates these guessable hyperlinks, so that a page numbered with "I" or "II" gets the link name `page.I`/`page.II` while with `hypertexnames=false` the number after `page` is the current value of `\Hy@linkcounter`, so the numbers are unique, but bear little or no relation to the actual counter of the particular object you're referencing. `biblatex` uses the `page` counter to create links for backrefs (it refers to `page.<\thepage>`), so the page links have to be of the former kind.

Comment: The reason why `plainpages=false` did not help you - I guess - is because you turned off the much more powerful `hypertexnames`, which implicitly makes the changes to `plainpages` useless.

Comment: Yes, the answer from your 'edit2' is the first one which works for me as well. Have you had any issues since then?

Comment: no issues since then, everthing works fine. if you are using  `auto-pst-pdf` turn it off after processing the modified .eps. files, then rerun pdflatex.